# How to position view relative to parent?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with an MKMapView in it.  In viewDidLoad of this controller, I add the MKMapView:

```
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

I want to display this map in a tableview cell.  In the tableview controller's cellForRowAtIndexPath:, I do this:

```
[cell addSubview:mapView.view];
```

where cell is a UITableViewCell.  I've set the mapview frame to

```
mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100);
```

The mapview appears to the bottom left of the cell. Meaning, it is partially in the cell and also out of it.  The map overlaps much of the cell but I want it to fill the cell and be bounded by it.  How can that be done?

There isn't an associated xib for these controllers.

--- EDIT ------

The tableview is styled as grouped.  It looks as though I just need to do some trial and error offsetting to get the map matched up correctly.

Comment: Your question is unclear: are you trying to add *the same mapview object* that you've added to your view controller's view also into a table cell? If not, you can remove the first part of your question where you talk about adding a map to a view controller. Adding a map to a view controller and adding a map to a table cell are two different things, which require different frame geometry.

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting the clipbounds property on the mapview?

Comment: I set clipbounds to true on the mapview and UIViewController. Doesn't make any difference